# Input validation in c programming

Tags: c

I have a small project from my college about phone book. I have a little problem to validate the first character of the name, and I use ascii to validate the first character of the name. the first character of the name should be (A-Z) or (a-z),  can someone help me solve my problem? thanks!

```
#pragma warning (disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   char name[30];
   int flag;
   int i;

   printf("Add New Contact\n");

   start:
   do {
      printf("input name[1..30 chars]: ");
      scanf("%s", name); fflush(stdin);

      for (i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
         if (name[1] >= 65 && name[1] <= 90 || name[1] >= 97 && name[1] <= 122) {
            flag = 1;
         }
         else {
            printf("First letter of name should be an alphabet (A-Z or a-z)\n");
            getchar();
            goto start;
         }
      }
   } while (flag == 0);

   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be an angel and don't use a goto until you've been programming for 10,000 hours.

Comment: Read documentation of every used function, e.g. [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`).  Your code is not portable to systems having non-ASCII character encoding (e.g. EBCDIC)

Comment: Given that you are a newcomer to Stackoverflow, please read [ask].

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First element of an array has index 0. Change to:

```
(name[0] >= 65 && name[0] <= 90 || name[0] >= 97 && name[0] <= 122)
```

And it would have been more readable if you used char litterals, change to:

```
(name[0] >= 'A' && name[0] <= 'Z' || name[0] >= 'a' && name[0] <= 'z')
```

There also exists an `isalpha` function that can make the test for you...

Also don't put your test inside a for loop, you stated that you wanted to test the first letter only, so why a loop? That should looks like (also removing `goto` and `fflush`, unnecessary `getchar`, and adding parenthesis to help reading the condition):

```
do {
  printf("input name[1..30 chars]: ");
  scanf("%s", name);
  if ( (name[0] >= 'A' && name[0] <= 'Z') || (name[0] >= 'a' && name[0] <= 'z') ) {
      flag = 1;
  }
  else {
      printf("First letter of name should be an alphabet (A-Z or a-z)\n");
  }
} while (flag == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks alott man !! can you teach me how to use isalpha ? i wish i can be as good as you in programming haha !

Comment: Before asking such a question please try to read a manual or a tutorial. `isalpha(name[0])` should do the trick.

Comment: @AlbertusFar - Hope your issue is solved. Please accept the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The first char of an array starts at index `0`, not `1`. So, you need change it to:

```
  if (name[0] >= 65 && name[0] <= 90 || name[0] >= 97 && name[0] <= 122) {

   }
```

You can use [isalpha()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) which is even  simple and portable.

Note that `fflush(stdin);` is *undefined behaviour* in ISO C.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (name[1] >= 65 && name[1] <= 90 || name[1] >= 97 && name[1] <= 122) {
        flag = 1;
    }
```

`name[1]` will check for second character not first . Array indexing start with `0` (`0` to `29` *in your case* ), so first character is `name[0]`.

A point - instead of calculating string length inside loop , calculate it first ,store into variable and then use it in condition.

**Note**- When you use `do-while` loop then why do you even use `goto` . Loop is going to iterate any way (*ofcourse until* `flag` is not `1`). There is no need of it .